# Set focus to UserControl Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm developing UserControl for WindowsPhone.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
           x:Name="DImage"/>
</Grid>
```

And in code-behind I have DependencyProperty

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(DragImage), new PropertyMetadata(ImageSourceChanged));

    private static void ImageSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var userControl = d as UserControl;
        if (userControl != null) 
            userControl.Focus();
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

When ImageSource is changed, I want this control to get focused.
But it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that focus is not getting by using GotFocus event of the usercontrol?

Comment: @JagathMurali yes, I have.

Comment: if you are not getting the Focus in the Image control(which you verified using the GotFocus event), then the Object in the ImageSourceChanged event may not be the Image Control?

Comment: @JagathMurali object in ImageSourceChanged is my control, and I set focus for it.

Comment: you should replace `UserControl` with `DragImage`

Comment: @verdesrobert It doesn'n help.

Comment: is your `d` an `UserControl` or `DragImage`?

Comment: @verdesrobert d is a DragImage

Comment: Does your code reach the `d.Focus();`?

Comment: @verdesrobert yes, of course

Comment: Try to encapsulate it in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: @verdesrobert I tried, but it doesn't help

Is it possible in general to set focus to non text controls?

Comment: in fact the usercontrol must have some Focusable items in it